# Finding a Culture with the same Language

Tags: c#, culture

I am working on a globalization project using .resx resourse files. I have some fallback logic  in case the language that the user selected doesn't have a resx file. Is there a way to find a culture that has the same language but a different region than a supplied culture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resources that are specific to a language, but not to a specific culture, should be in their own file, e.g. if you have the following resource files:

```
Resources.resx
Resources.en.resx
Resources.fr.resx
Resources.fr-FR.resx
```

(language-invariant strings in `Resources.resx`, French strings in `Resources.fr.resx`, and France-specific French strings in `Resources.fr-FR.resx`)

And the user's culture is `fr-CA` (Canadian French), then it will use resources from the following files, in this order:

```
Resources.fr.resx
Resources.resx
```

This is the default resource behavior.

Comment: Will there actually be a fallback from `fr-FR` to `fr-CA` with this, as implied by the question ("different region")?

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to rewrite some code to make it work like this though.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper no, there won't. Instead, you should set up your resource files so that ones that apply to both are in the `fr` file. You shouldn't need to look in `fr-FR` for anything if your culture is `fr-CA`.

Comment: @TimS.: Interesting - this implies that basically, everything should at first go directly into `fr` and remain there, to have as much fallback capacity available as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then you're looking for something like cultures with same languages

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("fr");
var sameLanguageCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures)
    .Where(x => x.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName == culture.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName && x.Name != culture.Name)
    .ToArray();

foreach (var c in sameLanguageCultures)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
}
```

this will output

```
fr-FR
fr-BE 
fr-CA
fr-CH
fr-LU
fr-MC
```

Make it clear if am wrong.